# How to use simple variable expansion in an Automake script as in a GNU Make script?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

There are [two flavors](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) of a variable in GNU Make: "[recursively expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursive-Assignment.html)" and "[simply expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Assignment.html)". `VARIABLE:=VALUE` yields simple expansion in Makefile but seems to yield recursive expansion in Makefile.am. Here is an example. GNU Make outputs `common` after running it with the following snippet in Makefile.

```
a = common
b := $(a)
a = A
$(info $(b))
```

When I put the same snippet into Makefile.am, autotools generate a Makefile containing the following code.

```
a = A
b := $(a)
...
$(info $(b))
```

Naturally, this time Make outputs `A`. I want to have Make output `common`. Is there a way to use the simple expansion semantics in Makefile.am? (There is no original problem I want to solve: I've stumbled across this question several times and want to understand how variables work in Automake scripts better).

Comment: I don't know what `$(simple b)` means.  As far as make is concerned, that's trying to expand a weirdly-named variable `simple b`.

Comment: @MadScientist I see, I misinterpreted the flavor function. I believe I took the use case from the internet but fail to find it now. Anyhow thanks, I removed the part about my unreasonable attempt from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can't.

First, a primary goal of automake is to generate makefiles that conform to the POSIX definition of make, so that the makefiles so output do *not* require GNU make.

Second, as described in the [General Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#General-Operation) section of automake, simple variables are explicitly warned about as non-standard / non-portable.  And in any event, as described there as well, the generated `Makefile.in` is rearranged from the `Makefile.am` to put all the variables first in the output; that means that any overriding of the same variable will be condensed into a single value (as you've seen in your experiments).